# Prove or disprove: Suppose $f'$ is continuous in a nbd of $c$ and $f'(c)>0$. Then $f$ is strictly increasing in some nbd of $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I previously posted a similar question and it seems it doesn't lead to the same conclusion if $f$ is not continuous.
[if $f'(c)<0$ then there exists a nbd $I$ of $c$ such that $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3011752/151611) . I understand now why it doesn't hold.

Here's an attempt of proof with $f'$ being continuous in a nbd of $c$:

Since we have that $f'(c)>0$, there must be $\delta >0$ such that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \in (c-\delta , c+\delta )$. This is obtained by letting $\varepsilon := f'(c)/2 > 0$ and using the definition of continuity. Since $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \in (c-\delta , c+\delta )$, it must be that $f$ is strictly increasing in this  particular nbd of $c$. This completes the proof.

Is this okay? Or am I still going wrong anywhere?

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: You could also use the definition of the derivative: $$\forall\epsilon>0, \epsilon\in nbd(c), \frac{f(c+\epsilon)-f(c)}{\epsilon}>0 \Rightarrow f(c+\epsilon) > f(c) \text{because } \epsilon \text{ is positive}$$ Thus $f$ is strictly increasing in a nbd of $c$